# How can I divide two floats and get an integer

Tags: java

I have two variables that are both floats, and I want the division to return as an integer. I've tried a few things, such as Math.Round() and multiplying it by 1, then dividing by 1, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Calculator
  {
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {

        float firstNumber;
        float secondNumber;
        char operator;
        float answer;
        float answerRemainder;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


        System.out.print("Enter your first number");
        firstNumber = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the operator (s for subtraction, a for addition, m for multiplication, d for division, r for division with a remainder))\n");
        operator = input.next().charAt(0);
        while (operator != 's' && operator != 'a' && operator != 'm' && operator != 'd' && operator != 'r')

        {
           System.out.print("\nYou have entered an incorrect character. Enter the operator (s for subtraction, a for addition, m for multiplication, d for division, r for division with a remainder)\n");
           operator = input.next().charAt(0);
        }

        System.out.print("Enter your second number");
        secondNumber = input.nextInt();

        if (operator == 's')

        {
           System.out.print(firstNumber +" - "+secondNumber+" = "+(firstNumber - secondNumber));
        }

        else if (operator == 'a')

        {
           System.out.print(firstNumber +" + "+secondNumber+" = "+(firstNumber + secondNumber));
        }

        else if (operator == 'm')

        {
           System.out.print(firstNumber+" * "+secondNumber+" = "+(firstNumber * secondNumber));
        }      

        else if (operator == 'd')

        {
           System.out.print(firstNumber+" / "+secondNumber+" = "+(firstNumber / secondNumber));
        }

        else if (operator == 'r')

        {
            answerRemainder = (firstNumber / secondNumber);
            System.out.print(firstNumber+" / "+secondNumber+" = "+(answerRemainder)+" with a remainder of "+(firstNumber % secondNumber));
        }
     }
  }
```

So I want the last line "answerRemainder" to be a whole number

Comment: Round the result with `Math.round`. Or `Math.floor`. Or `Math.ceiling`. Depends on what you want.

Comment: Cast your division to `int` like `answerRemainder = (int) (firstNumber / secondNumber);`

Comment: @aribeiro that will truncate - the OP might not want to do that.

Comment: True, but using `floor` or `ceiling` would also truncate. It's just a question of either the OP cares or not with the truncation.

Comment: @aribeiro Thanks that's exactly what I wanted. How do I mark as solved?

Comment: I've posted my answer. Nevertheless, you should take into account what @BoristheSpider mentioned, and see if doing the `ceiling` or the `floor` isn't relevant to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your division to `int` like `answerRemainder = (int) (firstNumber / secondNumber);`

Nevertheless, as was pointed out on the question comments, doing the above will result on the loss of precision.

Without any cast, having `firstNumber = 3.4f` and `secondNumber = 1.2f`, the result of `firstNumber / secondNumber` would be `2.8333333`.

Using the cast, the result would be `2.0`, since an `int` is a number without precision, the result is truncated and the precision is discarded.

Rounding the result upwards, using the [ceiling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) (`Math.ceil`), the result would be **rounded up** and you would get the integer **after** `2.8333333`, which would be `3.0`.

Rounding the result downwards, using the [floor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) (`Math.floor`), the result would be **rounded down** and you would get the integer **before** `2.8333333`, which would be `2.0`.

**Note**: The `f` on both variables' values is necessary because without it, by default, Java would interpret the values as a `double`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I'm sorry for not completing my answer. Hope the edit may clarify everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
Float  float_variable = (float) fistNumber/(float) secondNumber;

  answerRemainder =  Math.round(float_variable);
```